# CUDA: Is texture memory still useful to speed up access times for compute capability 2.x and newer?

Tags: cuda

I'm writing an image processing app where I have to fetch pixel data in uncoalesced manner.

Initially I implemented my algorithm using global memory. Later I reimplemented it using texture memory. To my amazement it became slower! I thought, maybe something wrong with cudaMalloc/text1Dfetch style, so I changed it to cudaArray/tex2D. Nothing changed.

Then I stumbled upon Shane Cook's "CUDA Programming", where he wrote:

> As compute 1.x hardware has no cache to speak of, the 6–8K of texture memory per SM provides the
>   only method to truly cache data on such devices. However, with the advent of Fermi and its up to 48 K
>   L1 cache and up to 768 K shared L2 cache, this made the usage of texture memory for its cache
>   properties largely obsolete. The texture cache is still present on Fermi to ensure backward compati-
>   bility with previous generations of code.

I have GeForce GT 620M (Fermi, compute cap. 2.1).

So I need some advice from professionals! Should I dig deeper into texture memory with its texture cache trying to optimize performance? Or I should better stick with global memory and L1/L2 cache?

Comment: I would say no. Since Fermi architecture, the cache hierarchy works better than the texture's cache (atleast in some test I did in Fermi). However, textures are still useful for interpolation and probably for some processes involving rendering (not my topic).

Comment: I think it depends on whether you are making use of other features of the texturing hardware: mainly texture addressing and filtering calculations and optional promote-to-float.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Textures can indeed be useful on devices of compute capability >= 2.0.

Textures and cudaArrays can use memory stored in a [space filling curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve), which can allow for a better cache hit rate due to better 2D spatial locality.

The texture cache is separate from the other caches. So it has its own dedicated memory and bandwidth and reading from it does not interfere with the other caches. This can become important if there is a lot of pressure on your L1/L2 caches.

Textures also provide built in functionality such as interpolation, various addressing modes (clamp, wrap, mirror) and normalized addressing with floating point coordinates. These can be used without any extra cost and can greatly improve performance in kernels where such functionality is needed.

On early CUDA architectures, textures and cudaArrays could not be written by a kernel. On architectures of compute capability >= 2.0, they can be written via CUDA surfaces.

Determining if you should use textures or a regular buffer in global memory comes down to the intended usage and access patterns for the memory. It will be project specific.

You are using the Fermi architecture, with a device that has been rebranded into the 6xx series.

For those on the Kepler architecture, take a look at NVIDIA's [Inside Kepler](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/S0642-GTC2012-Inside-Kepler.pdf) Presentation. In particular, the slides, `Texture Performance`, `Texture Cache Unlocked` and `const __restrict Example`.

Comment: I worked on at least one real-life code where the use of textures provided useful speedup across sm_2x and sm_3x, even without using texture interpolation. The benefit of using textures was that this application's data access pattern in a 2D matrix was a better match for the texture cache. In other words, I echo Roger's remark that the benefit will be project specific.