# Is 1D texture memory access faster than 1D global memory access?

Tags: cuda

I am measuring the difference between the standard and 1Dtexture  access to memory. To do so I have created two kernels

```
__global__ void texture1D(float* doarray,int size)
{
  int index;
  //calculate each thread global index
  index=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
  //fetch global memory through texture reference
  doarray[index]=tex1Dfetch(texreference,index);
  return;
}
__global__ void standard1D(float* diarray, float* doarray, int size)
{
  int index;
  //calculate each thread global index
  index=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
  //fetch global memory through texture reference
  doarray[index]= diarray[index];
  return;
}
```

Then, I call eache kernel measuring the time it takes:

```
//copy array from host to device memory
  cudaMemcpy(diarray,harray,sizeof(float)*size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  checkCuda( cudaEventCreate(&startEvent) );
  checkCuda( cudaEventCreate(&stopEvent) );
  checkCuda( cudaEventRecord(startEvent, 0) );

  //bind texture reference with linear memory
  cudaBindTexture(0,texreference,diarray,sizeof(float)*size);

  //execute device kernel
  texture1D<<<(int)ceil((float)size/threadSize),threadSize>>>(doarray,size);

  //unbind texture reference to free resource
  cudaUnbindTexture(texreference);

  checkCuda( cudaEventRecord(stopEvent, 0) );
  checkCuda( cudaEventSynchronize(stopEvent) );

  //copy result array from device to host memory
  cudaMemcpy(horray,doarray,sizeof(float)*size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  //check result
  checkResutl(horray, harray, size);

  cudaEvent_t startEvent2, stopEvent2;
  checkCuda( cudaEventCreate(&startEvent2) );
  checkCuda( cudaEventCreate(&stopEvent2) );
  checkCuda( cudaEventRecord(startEvent2, 0) );
  standard1D<<<(int)ceil((float)size/threadSize),threadSize>>>(diarray,doarray,size);
  checkCuda( cudaEventRecord(stopEvent2, 0) );
  checkCuda( cudaEventSynchronize(stopEvent2) );

  //copy back to CPU
  cudaMemcpy(horray,doarray,sizeof(float)*size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

and print results:

```
  float time,time2;
  checkCuda( cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, startEvent, stopEvent) );
  checkCuda( cudaEventElapsedTime(&time2, startEvent2, stopEvent2) );
  printf("Texture  bandwidth (GB/s): %f\n",bytes * 1e-6 / time);
  printf("Standard bandwidth (GB/s): %f\n",bytes * 1e-6 / time2);
```

It turns out that, no matters the size of the array I am allocating (`size`), the standard bandwidth is always much higher. 
Is that how it suppose to be or am I screwing it up at some point? 
My understanding of Texture memory access was that it can speed up global memory access.

Comment: Which architecture are you targeting? There is a useful and recent post at [CUDA: Is texture memory still useful to speed up access times for compute capability 2.x and newer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687778/cuda-is-texture-memory-still-useful-to-speed-up-access-times-for-compute-capabi). My experience is that, formulating the problem as in your post, i.e., using texture memory as cache only, its convenience for newer architectures is somewhat less than in the past. Perhaps when using texture for filtering there will be applications which may possibly benefit from its use.

Comment: @JackOLantern  Tesla K20

Comment: I would recommend do the test separately. If the execution time of your kernels is very small, your test might be affected by the time required to created a CUDA context. In this case, the second kernel is beneficiating for the first one which created the context (included in the time).

Comment: @pQB I have done that as well, but there is not much difference since I have a warming up kernel before to the execution of these 2 other kernels

Comment: Good to know. Then the comment of @JackOLantern would probably has the asnwer.

Comment: @pQB I agree. good post by the way

Comment: @JackOLantern if you will post your comments as an answer I would upvote

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have provided an answer trying to numerically justify the statement in comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have made a comparison between global memory and texture memory (used for caching purposes only, and not for filtering) for the interpolation of a 1D complex valued function.

The kernels I'm comparing are the `4`, `2` using global memory and `2` using texture memory. They are distinguished according to the way complex values are accessed (`1 float2` or `2 floats`) and are reported below. I will post somewhere the full Visual Studio 2010 in case someone like to make some criticisms or perform his own testing.

```
__global__ void linear_interpolation_kernel_function_GPU(float* __restrict__ result_d, const float* __restrict__ data_d, const float* __restrict__ x_out_d, const int M, const int N)
{
    int j = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    if(j<N)
    {
        float reg_x_out = x_out_d[j/2]+M/2;
        int k = __float2int_rz(reg_x_out);
        float a = reg_x_out - __int2float_rz(k);
        float dk = data_d[2*k+(j&1)];
        float dkp1 = data_d[2*k+2+(j&1)];
        result_d[j] = a * dkp1 + (-dk * a + dk);
    } 
}

__global__ void linear_interpolation_kernel_function_GPU_alternative(float2* __restrict__ result_d, const float2* __restrict__ data_d, const float* __restrict__ x_out_d, const int M, const int N)
{
    int j = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    if(j<N)
    {
        float reg_x_out = x_out_d[j]+M/2;
        int k = __float2int_rz(reg_x_out);
        float a = reg_x_out - __int2float_rz(k);
        float2 dk = data_d[k];
        float2 dkp1 = data_d[k+1];
        result_d[j].x = a * dkp1.x + (-dk.x * a + dk.x);
        result_d[j].y = a * dkp1.y + (-dk.y * a + dk.y);
    } 
}

__global__ void linear_interpolation_kernel_function_GPU_texture(float2* __restrict__ result_d, const float* __restrict__ x_out_d, const int M, const int N)
{
    int j = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    if(j<N)
    {
        float reg_x_out = x_out_d[j]+M/2;
        int k = __float2int_rz(reg_x_out);
        float a = reg_x_out - __int2float_rz(k);
        float2 dk = tex1Dfetch(data_d_texture,k);
        float2 dkp1 = tex1Dfetch(data_d_texture,k+1);
        result_d[j].x = a * dkp1.x + (-dk.x * a + dk.x);
        result_d[j].y = a * dkp1.y + (-dk.y * a + dk.y);
    } 
}

__global__ void linear_interpolation_kernel_function_GPU_texture_alternative(float* __restrict__ result_d, const float* __restrict__ x_out_d, const int M, const int N)
{
    int j = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    if(j<N)
    {
        float reg_x_out = x_out_d[j/2]+M/4;
        int k = __float2int_rz(reg_x_out);
        float a = reg_x_out - __int2float_rz(k);
        float dk = tex1Dfetch(data_d_texture2,2*k+(j&1));
        float dkp1 = tex1Dfetch(data_d_texture2,2*k+2+(j&1));
        result_d[j] = a * dkp1 + (-dk * a + dk);
    } 
}
```

I have considered 4 different GPUs, namely, GeForce GT540M (cc 2.1), Tesla C2050 (cc 2.0), Kepler K20c (cc 3.5) and GT210 (cc 1.2). The results are reported in the figures below. As it can be seen, using textures as cache with older compute capabilities improves over the use of global memory, while the two solutions are pretty equivalent for the newest architecture.

Of course, this example is not exhaustive and there may be in practice other cases when the former or the latter should be preferred for particular applications.

p.s. The processing times are in [ms] and not in [s] as indicated in the figure labels.

[image: GT210]
[image: Tesla C2050]
[image: GeForce GT540M]
[image: Kepler K20c]

Comment: Possible micro-optimization: `int k = floorf(reg_x_out);` ==> `int k = __float2int_rd(reg_x_out);`. Unfortunately the compiler doesn't apply that optimization automatically. Similarly for `(int)truncf()` ==> `__float2int_rz()` and the other IEEE-754 rounding modes of course.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for the suggestions. I will apply your recommendations and provide new graphs.

Comment: @njuffa I have updated the figures according to your comment. I hope I have correctly interpreted the use of intrinsics with particular reference to roundings. I'm now going to see what happens with texture filtering.

Comment: What I was suggesting is the following idiom using minimal number of conversions instructions and maximum amount of ILP: `int k = __float2int_rz(reg_x_out); float a = reg_x_out - truncf(reg_x_out);`. As I said, these are micro optimizations that may not make a difference in most cases [but I have seen at least one real life interpolation kernel where trimming every last instruction was crucial for maximizing performance].