# Is it possible to speed up matrix multiplication with texture memory?

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, multiplication

I am learning cuda.

Would it be possible to speedup something as simple as matrix multiplication with texture memory? The spatial locality is a nice property as addition to my tiling, but could overhead from using texture memory outweigh it?

I can't seem to find any implementations of matrix multiplication that use texture memory.

Comment: It may be useful for you to review this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25821131/3242721).

Comment: Thank you. It's a good thread indeed. However I am still uncertain about this particular task, so I'll answer to myself in a few days if noone have done it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix multiply can be implemented in a variety of ways.

Compared to a naive implementation of matrix multiply that only uses global memory, yes, it's possible to speed it up using texture memory.

Compared to a better-written version of matrix multiply that uses shared memory, it's not likely that texture memory will give much or any benefit.

If you want the best performance from CUDA matrix multiply, you should use CUBLAS.  Don't write your own matrix multiply code.